# How to return only integers from a variable in Shell Script and discard letters and leading zeros?

Tags: linux, shell

In my shell script there is a parameter that comes from certain systems and it gives an answer similar to this one: PAR0000008.
And I need to send only the last number of this parameter to another variable, ie VAR=8.
I used the command `VAR=$( echo ${PAR} | cut -c 10 )` and it worked perfectly.
The problem is when the PAR parameter returns with numbers from two decimal places like PAR0000012. I need to discard the leading zeros and send only the number 12 to the variable, but I don't know how to do the logic in the Shell to discard all the characters to the left of the number.

Comment: Does the regular expression "PAR0*[1-9][0-9]*" capture the patterns you expect?

Comment: unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit Using `grep` To Handle 0 As Part Of Final Number**

Since you are using POSIX shell, making use of a utility like `sed` or `grep` (or `cut`) makes sense. `grep` is quite a bit more flexible in parsing the string allowing a REGEX match to handle the job. Say your variable `v=PAR0312012` and you want the result `r=312012`. You can use a *command substitution* (e.g. `$(...)`) to parse the value assigning the result to `r`, e.g.

```sh
v=PAR0312012
r=$(echo $v | grep -Eo '[1-9].*$')
echo $r
```

The `grep` expression is:

- `-Eo` - use Extended REGEX and only return matching portion of string,
- `[1-9].*$` - from the first character in `[1-9]` return the remainder of the string.

This will work for `PAR0000012` or `PAR0312012` (with result `312012`).

**Result**

For `PAR0312012`

```
312012
```

---

**Another Solution Using `expr`**

If your variable can have zeros as part of the final number portion, then you must find the index where the first `[1-9]` character occurs, and then assign the substring beginning at that index to your result variable.

POSIX shell provides `expr` which provides a set of string parsing tools that can to this. The needed commands are:

```sh
expr index string charlist
```

and

```sh
expr substr string start end
```

Where `start` and `end` are the beginning and ending indexes to extract from the string. `end` just has to be long enough to encompass the entire substring, so you can just use the total length of your string, e.g.

```sh
v=PAR0312012
ndx=$(expr index "$v" "123456789")
r=$(expr substr "$v" "$ndx" 10)
echo $r
```

**Result**

```
312012
```

This will handle `0` anywhere after the first `[1-9]`.

(**note:** the old `expr ...` isn't the fastest way of handling this, but if you are only concerned with a few tens of thousands of values, it will work fine. A billion numbers and another method will likely be needed)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
For returns that do not end in zero the code works correctly, but for numbers ending in zero, such as 10 or 100, the code returns the integer parameter PAR0000010

Comment: Yes, If you want to find the first non-zero index, you can use the old `expr index str charlist`. I'll edit and add that to the answer.

Comment: @TomAL - See the updated answer. The `grep` solution will be the fastest. The solution using `expr` is there if you have to use only shell provided expressions.

Comment: David, thanks a lot! You've helped too much! God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using [**Parameter  Expension**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```sh
var='PAR0000008'
echo "${var##*0}"
//prints 8
echo "${var##*[^1-9]}"
//prints 8
var="${var##*0}"
echo "$var"
//prints 8

var='PAR0000012'
echo "${var##*0}"
//prints 12
echo "${var##*[^1-9]}"
//prints 12
var="${var##*[^1-9]}"
echo "$var"
//prints 12
```